# pywinusb cant read or write data

Tags: pywinusb

I have a custom HID device that, for testing pywinusb, returns anything that I send it. I think that I am sending the data correctly but I'm not receiving anything back. I tested the device with a terminal that can communicate with usb devices so, I know that when I send it something I get something back, ie i send [0x55, 0x00,...., 0x00] and I get 0x55,...,0x55 back.

when I run my code this is what i get:

> [HID device (vID=0x0001, pID=0x0001, v=0x0001); Unipampa; Kaki, Path: \?\hid#vid_0001&pid_0001#6&2d07b355&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}]
>   None

This is the code that I'm running:

```js
import sys
import pywinusb.hid as hid

def readData(data):
    print(data)
    return None

filter = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id = 0x0001, product_id = 0x0001)
hid_device = filter.get_devices()
device = hid_device[0]
device.open()
print(hid_device)


'''Send data'''
dataOut = device.find_output_reports()

buffer= [0xFF]*65
buffer[0] = 63

dataOut[0].set_raw_data(buffer)
dataOut[0].send()


''' Read data '''
dataIn = device.set_raw_data_handler(readData)
print(dataIn)
```

I'm just trying to get a simple write read to work.